# Indicators when designing custom SeekBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, seekbar

[image]

I want to design a `SeekBar` exactly like that. In the picture you can see the `SeekBar` stops on different positions. I have done that but I am not able to show indicators in the background of `SeekBar which will be compatible for all the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Take a text view.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Place it where you like to place the indicator in xml.
Suppose according to the 25 progress of seekbar you like to show the progress in the indicator.

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener seekbarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(progress == 100)
        {
           tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
        }
        else if(progress == 75)
        {
           tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
        }
        else if(progress == 50)
        {
           tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
        }

        else if(progress == 25)
        {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
        }
        else if(progress == 0)
        {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));       
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

I just give an example that what you can do with it. You do according to the requirement.

Comment: I am sorry to say but this is not help full. I have to show indicators within the seek bar not on some other widget. that thing I can do. Please see image carefully indicators are within seek bar

Comment: Well then you have to do it by custom image. I have done it. Try it.

Comment: I have also done it but its not multi device support
I have applied it on my code but its not applicable for every device and I need exactly that. If you have done can you please provide me code.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya Did you got any solution for this. If you got solution means can you share me. I need this same way

Comment: @G.MURALIRaja Sorry my friend I didnt get any solution for this task m also looking for some solution

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya Thanks for your fast reply friend. Am expecting like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911151/is-it-possible-scale-rating-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a TextView. Then in onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) method you will get the progress of the seekbar. Show the indicator text in the textview according to the progress. I have did it in this way. You can try it.

Comment: can you elaborate it more please