# Is it possible scale rating bar in android?

Tags: android

Android have the default star rating bar instead of star how can i use scale rating. Does any have implemented like that. Please share your valuable ideas.

Ex: Am expecting user click on the scale four value scale fills up to four, etc..

How can i achieve like this.

Sample Images:

[image] [image]

It will changes fill values may be 4,5,8,9 like that. how to do like that. share your ideas

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

May be you could extend [Seek Bar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) and create your own rating scale widget.

Comment: Hi Siva, SeekBar once its start it will end with the last edge. i want user click on the 4 th value in scale it will comes only till 4 th value. can you understand what am expecting